# Importing variables from python modules

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I have a module called tb_batch in python. The content is :

```
m_d = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%B') + '_' + str(dt.datetime.now().year)
```

When I tried importing this variable into another python program using,

```
from tb_batch import m_d
```

It throws error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tb_batch' has no attribute 'm_d'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error, works perfectly fine on my end (with `tb_batch.py` containing `import datetime as dt` and the line you quoted). Can you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us that displays the error?

Comment: I am working with jupyter notebook. When I tried this same code in Visual studio code, it works perfectly

Comment: `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5e9764232617> in <module>()
      1 import tb_batch
----> 2 print(tb_batch.tb_path)

AttributeError: module 'tb_batch' has no attribute 'tb_path'`

Comment: `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-e883f7ca7e7a> in <module>()
----> 1 tb_batch.m_d

AttributeError: module 'tb_batch' has no attribute 'm_d'
`

Comment: I don't have much experience with [tag:jupyter-notebook]. Please tag it so, so people with relevant expertise can find your question more easily.

Comment: Thank you the issue has been resolved. I just use visual studio to run my code

Comment: If so, it would be great if you could either write your own answer showing exactly what was wrong and how you resolved it (or close the question).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with jupyter cells. I have run my code in VisualStudioCode and it is working fine. Thanks all for your contribution